# Get sub string aws_vpc cidir block using terraform functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I'm learning terraform and having issue with get sub string of vpc cidr blocks

For example:

```
VPC1: 10.0.0.0/16
VPC2: 172.31.0.0/16
VPC3: 192.168.0.0/16
```

**I'd like to get sub string before second "." from above VPCs:**

```
VPC1: 10.0
VPC2: 172.31
VPC3: 192.168
```

How can I get those string with terraform built-in functions?

Thanks and have a good day

Comment: `split` at the dots and then take the first and second results and combine them with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/regex):

```
> regex("\\d+\\.\\d+", "10.0.0.0/16")
"10.0"
> regex("\\d+\\.\\d+", "172.31.0.0/16")
"172.31"
> regex("\\d+\\.\\d+", "192.168.0.0/16")
"192.168"
```

Comment: thanks @Marcin, your answer is helpful.